# Load data, insert after and slidetoggle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, accordion

I`m kind of novice in jquery and want to make a sliding table.
The orinal table has 3 levels:

```
<ul class="categories">
<li id="category1">1 element</li>  //parentid=0
<li id="category2">2 element</li>  //parentid=0
<ul>
<li id="category3">1 element of element id2</li>  //parentid=2
<ul>
<li id="category4">1 element id3</li>  //parentid=3
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The first level elements have parentid = 0, id=1++, the next level have nested parentid and there own id and so on.

Page loads with only 1 level with parentid = 0.

```
<ul class="categories">
<li id="category1">1 element</li>  //parentid=0
<li id="category2">2 element</li>  //parentid=0
</ul>
```

Then I want to click the li, take id ID - go to file, execute mysql, get the new table in variable, bring it back and slideToggle it under LI.

**php side**

```
if(isset($_POST['subcategory'])){
    $subcategory = str_replace('category', '', $_POST['subcategory']);  
    echo build_category_tree($subcategory); // builds the UL tree
}
```

this returns me id, i need to return the list and toggle it.

NOW the new UL is connected BUT i jquery cant work with it, updated the script with the one below but still cant.

**UPDATED JQuery**

```
    $(".tablecategoryname").on('click', function(){
    var $a = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
    var $c = $(this).closest('li');

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "functions.php",
       data: {subcategory:$a},
       cache: false,
       success: function(data)
       {
            $(data).hide().insertAfter($c).slideDown(400);
       }
     });    
});
```

Comment: $("#1 li").append('<li>bla bla</li>'); ?

Comment: thats not so simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID's should not contain just a number (or start with a number), you should probably use `#a1` or something similar. In the data parameter you're sending an object, and equalsigns does'nt really work.

```
$(".table li").on('click', function(){
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "functions.php",
       data: {id : self.id},
       cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        //guessing you're returning valid HTML
        $(data).hide().insertAfter(self).slideDown(400);
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Your build_category_tree() function needs to return the HTML so you can echo it back to the ajax request:

```
if(isset($_POST['subcategory'])){
    echo $subcategory = str_replace('category', '', $_POST['subcategory']); 
    $ULtree = build_category_tree($subcategory); // builds the UL tree
    echo $ULtree; //echo back to Ajax
}
```

Comment: updated the question, fixed id names, need to receive the function data and toggle it under the li

Comment: @mozg - edited my answer. I don't know how your function that builds the HTML works, but you need to echo out the HTML so it can be returned as the response in the ajax function.

Comment: did that and it returns the data, but jquery doesnt work with the new inserted li, updated my script, but still doesnt work, updated my script upper

Answer (score 0):

You should put an id in your main ul to catch his parent and them toggle the list inside the main ul.

$("ul.umenu > li).click(function (e) {

```
    e.preventDefault();

    var element = $(this);

    if (element.parent().find("ul").is(":visible")) {
    } else {

        $("ul.umain> li > ul").slideUp();

        element.parent().find("ul").slideToggle("fast");

    }

});
```